# What is a class object in Objective-C 2.0?

Tags: objective-c

In the official documentation for **Objective C 2.0** titled **The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language** from Apple, released in 2009, there is a paragraph about Class Objects on page 28.

I don't understand what Class Objects are, and how to define them aside from the rest of the language and what properties they have. In the same document it's explained that everything in Objective-C 2.0 is an object, this object is basically a pointer to a `struct` that contains an `isa` field and the pointer itself is of type `id`.
From this I'm deducing that:

- inheritance in Obj-C 2.0 basically consists in chaining those `struct` through the `id` and `isa` field

  - objects that are superclass construct the `isa` field in a way that it points to a `nil` object.
- `id` is a valid datatype for pretty much everything in Objective C 2.0
- when defining a class, everything that defines the class itself ( methods and variables ) is packed starting from after/below the `isa` pointer

Assuming that I got how Objective C 2.0 works, what is a class object and how is it different from the way instances are created? What kind of properties does a class object offer that an instance doesn't have ? Can you make a parallel with C or C++?

Comment: You will undoubtedly be interested in [\[objc explain\]: Classes and metaclasses](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html), and the next article, ["Non-fragile ivars"](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html).

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, so this "thing" is also named `metaclass` ?

Comment: No, classes are their own thing. Metaclasses are the classes of classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so you define a class. We'll call him Charlie:

```
@interface Charlie : NSObject
@end
```

There's our little class! Since — like every other class in Obective-C — Charlie is an object, you can send it messages like `[Charlie alloc]` to have Charlie allocate an instance for you. This is what we mean by a class object: It's the object that represents the class you defined.

What is an object in Objective-C? Classes are defined based on this struct:

```
struct objc_object {
    Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;
};
```

And a class is represented by a struct like this:

```
struct objc_class {         
    struct objc_class *isa; 
    struct objc_class *super_class; 
    // A bunch of other members …
}
```

As you can see, the both start with an `isa` referring to a class. So a class is just an extension of normal objects.

When Charlie creates an instance, that instance's `isa` will point to Charlie. But what does Charlie's `isa` point to? Well, it points to a metaclass. A metaclass is a strange thing — it's a special kind of class that exists just to act as a class's class. You never interact with it directly; it just does its classly duties† when you interact with its sole instance, Charlie.

So that's what we mean when we talk about a class object — it's just the object that represents the class you defined in code.

† You might be wondering what a class's duties are. Well, the obvious biggie is that it's how you create your objects. But besides that, instances in Objective-C do not hold their own methods. Instead, method resolution is done based on an object's `isa`, so the class's most important function, besides creating instances for you, is determining what methods your object has.

Comment: ok, at this point I have just one doubt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105314/what-is-a-class-object-in-objective-c-2-0#comment33532987_22105629

Answer (score 2):

> what is a class object and how it's different from the way instances
>   are created ? What kind of properties a class object offers that an
>   instance doesn't have ? Can you make a parallel with C or C++ ?

Let's try to compare with C and C++. First there is no comparison to C, because C is not object oriented, so the concept of **object** or **class** does not exist. In C++ you have classes (or objects) which you declare in your **.h** file, there you write the definition of the class (the name, the instance variables, and methods or functions), and then in your **.cpp** file you implement the methods declared in the definition.
Also in C++ you can have **static** variables and methods, which, as you probably know, don't belong to a specific instance of the class, we could say that they affect *all instances*.

In objective C, a **class property** or a **class method** is analogous to the **static variables** and **static funcions** in C++.

A **class object** is the way objective C *encapsulates* the definition of a class and makes it available at runtime. You don't necessarily instantiate class objects explicitly.

Consider this class

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    int i;
}
- (void)myFunction;
+ (void)classFunction;
@end
```

You can instantiate such an object using:

```
MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

Here you're using the `alloc` method of the `MyObject` **class object**. Something important to understand is that you don't instantiate class Objects, the compiler creates just one object, a class object, to represent the class.

Comment: so if I repeat the same declaration for N `obj` I'll end up with N `obj` with an `id` pointing to the same `object` ?

Comment: @user2485710: If by "id" you mean "isa pointer", then yes, creating a bunch of instances of this class will result in a bunch of instances that all have their isa pointer pointing to this class. (In some kinda weird cases the isa might actually point to a subclass of that class, but in the most common and basic case, the isa will point to the class you used to create the object.)

Comment: Not exactly, `id` is just a 'synonym' for `void*` it is just a pointer without a specific type. `MyObject *obj` would be equivalent to `id obj` (but the compiler treats them differently). That being said, each of your N objects' `id` would point to a different object.

Comment: Apparently Chuck's comment contradicts mine, so I hope you don't get confused. Chuck's comment is based on `id` meaining 'isa pointer'... My comment considers `id` meaning `void*`.

Comment: @Chuck I think that I have grasped what it's going on, thanks to both of you

Comment: @Merlevede: Well, I was saying that I think he misused the term "id" to mean "isa pointer," not that the two terms are identical. However, I don't think it's right to say `id` is a synonym for `void*` — instead, it's the same as `struct objc_object*`. Unlike with a `void*`, if you try to assign, say, an `int*` to an `id` variable, you will get a warning.

Comment: @Chuck I have to agree with you. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

**Object** is a structure, that has `isa` field pointing to its Class. This `isa` allows the structure to receive Objective-C messages, which makes it an Object. Class pointed by `isa` is used to lookup implementations for these messages.

*(Interestingly, also blocks are objects and GCD structures are too. They both can receive messages, like `-copy` for blocks or `-description` for `dispatch_queue`.)*

**Class** is a structure used to look-up methods of its instances. It has a list of method implementations for their instances (`-methods`). Classes have an `isa` field, so they qualify as Objects, thus can also receive messages. `isa` of Class points to a Metaclass, so a Class is instance of a Metaclass. Its single instance – a singleton.

**Metaclass** is where I'm getting lost, but it's definitely an Object, because it has `isa`. Metaclass has a list of method implementations (`+methods`) of its single instance – the Class.

When you write this code:

```
@interface MYObject : NSObject
+ (void)classMethod; // Stored in Metaclass
- (void)instanceMethod; // Stored in Class
@end
```

You are creating a **pair: Class and Metaclass**.

*Oh, and what is a class of Metaclass? A Root Metaclass!*
*And what is a class of the Root Metaclass? The Root Metaclass itself!*
*But then where `isa` of Metaclasses points to? To our old friend `NSObject`. Too **meta**, right?*